Does Dante leave open the possibility of universalism in The Divine Comedy?
In the Inferno we see that the only souls liberated from Hell are the Old Testament saints, and all the other pre Christ people are consigned to hell, including the virtuous pagans.
However, in Paradise, we see pre Christ pagans, such as Trajan who went to hell, but was resurrected and converted through the intercessions of a pope.
Additionally, one of Dante the character's concerns within the Divine Comedy is the fate of those who never knew Christ, and consequently never had a chance at salvation.
So, by the inclusion of pagans in Paradise, through a mechanism of intercession, does this leave open the logical possibility of universal salvation through intercession of the saints?  For example, all the saints in Paradise could hypothetically intercede for the resurrection of everyone in hell to give everyone a chance to repent.

TL;DR: Dante, following Catholic orthodoxy, admits the salvation of some virtuous pagans, but denies universal salvation.
Salvation of virtuous pagans
The question of the salvation of virtuous pagans is considered in Paradiso canto 19. In this canto Dante is in the sphere of Jupiter, where he encounters the souls of the just, “more than a thousand” of whom (Par. 18.102) have formed themselves into the shape of “the head and shoulders of an eagle” (Par. 18.107) in order to converse with Dante. The eagle reminds Dante that he has often asked that question:

“For you used to say, ‘A man is born in sight
of Indus’ water, and there is none there
to speak of Christ, and none to read or write.
And all he wills and does, we must concede,
as far as human reason sees, is good;
and he does not sin either in word or deed.
He dies unbaptized and cannot receive
the saving faith. What justice is it damns him?
Is it his fault that he does not believe?’”
Dante (c. 1321). Paradiso, 19.70–78. Translated by John Ciardi (1691). New American Library.

In reply, the eagle first admonishes Dante:

“But who are you to take the judgment seat
and pass on things a thousand miles away,
who cannot see the ground before your feet?
Paradiso 19.79–81.

and then answers as follows:

                        “To this high empery
none ever rose but through belief in Christ,
either before or after his agony.”
Paradiso 19.103–105.

This seems at first to be an emphatic negative: the virtuous Indian did not believe in Christ, therefore he did not rise to heaven. But then in canto 20, the six souls who form the eagle’s eye, the “chief souls of all this blessed swarm” (Par. 20.36) are introduced to us, and two of them are pagans. First to be described is the emperor Trajan, who was noted in the question:

Of the five that form my eyebrow’s arc,
the one whose glory shines the closest to my beak
consoled the widow who had lost her son;
Paradiso 20.43–45.

But the last of the six souls is Ripheus the Trojan:

Who would believe in the erring world down there
that Ripheus the Trojan would be sixth
among the sacred lusters of this sphere?
Paradiso 20.67–69.

Who, we might well ask, is Ripheus the Trojan? He is a companion of Aeneas in Virgil’s Aeneid, and we know of no earlier source, so it is possible that Virgil invented him. This is all that Virgil has to say about him:

2.339 Rhipeus and Epytus, most mighty in arms, join company with me
2.394 So does Rhipeus, so Dymas in like wise, and all our men in delight arm themselves one by one in the fresh spoils.
2.426 Rhipeus falls, the one man who was most righteous and steadfast in justice among the Teucrians: the gods’ ways are not as ours.
Virgil (19 BCE). Aeneid. Translated by J. W. Mackail (1885). Project Gutenberg.

So Ripheus is a minor supporting character, about whom no other legends survive, someone of no particular significance. But this must be Dante’s point: how can Ripheus be numbered with David, Hezekiah, Constantine, and so on, if not by something extraordinary in divine grace? The eagle then explains how its earlier claim that “none ever rose but through belief in Christ” (Par. 19.104) can be reconciled with the salvation of Ripheus:

The other [Ripheus], by that grace whose blessings rise
out of so deep a spring that no one ever
has plumbed its sources with created eyes,
gave all his love to justice, there on earth,
and God, by grace on grace, let him foresee
a vision of our redemption shining forth.
So he believed in Christ, and all his days
shunning the poisonous stink of pagan creeds,
he warned the obstinant to change their ways.
Paradiso 20.43–45.

This idea of Ripheus, the Trojan hero, “most mighty in arms”, preaching the gospel to the pagans a thousand years before Saint Paul, is extravagant and ridiculous. But the extravagance must again be deliberate—if God has infinite grace, Dante seems to suggest, then to what lengths might he go to redeem people?
There is a theory (see Robert Hollander, 2007) that Dante selected Ripheus for this role in the poem as a rejoinder to Virgil’s comment that “the gods’ ways are not as ours” (dis aliter visum, literally “to the gods it seems otherwise”).
Although the story of Ripheus’s conversion may seem ridiculous, it is consistent with the claims of the scholastic theologians. Aquinas (who appears in Paradiso canto 10) says, first, that belief in Christ is necessary for salvation (compare Paradiso 19.103–105, quoted above):

Now the mystery of Christ’s Incarnation and Passion is the way by which men obtain beatitude; for it is written (Acts 4:12): There is no other name under heaven given to men, whereby we must be saved.
Thomas Aquinas (1274). Summa Theologiae 2-2.2.7. Anonymously translated (1917). New York: Benziger Brothers.

but also, that pre-Christian people believed in Christ, in some manner of speaking:

But after sin, man believed explicitly in Christ, not only as to the Incarnation, but also as to the Passion and Resurrection, whereby the human race is delivered from sin and death: for they would not, else, have foreshadowed Christ’s Passion by certain sacrifices both before and after the Law, the meaning of which sacrifices was known by the learned explicitly, while the simple folk, under the veil of those sacrifices, believed them to be ordained by God in reference to Christ’s coming, and thus their knowledge was covered with a veil, so to speak.

Dante’s story of the conversion of Ripheus is no more ridiculous than Aquinas’s theory here.
Universal salvation
So I think we can confident that Dante approved the salvation of virtuous pagans, whether post-Christian like Trajan, or pre-Christian like Ripheus. And the extravagance in the choice of Ripheus for one of the “chief souls” of the sphere of Jupiter indicates that he was prepared to go pretty far in this direction. But universal salvation is quite another matter. The pre-Christians who appear in heaven in the Divine Comedy were biblical patriarchs (Adam, Solomon, Joshua) or otherwise notably virtuous (Rachel, Rahab, Ripheus).
And the Divine Comedy contains multiple indications that souls in Hell (as opposed to Limbo) are damned for eternity. In Inferno, the inscription over the gates of hell reads, “Abandon all hope, ye who enter here” (Inf. 3.9), and Charon tells his passengers:

            “Woe to you depraved souls! Bury
here and forever all hope of Paradise:
I come to lead you to the other shore,
into eternal dark, into fire and ice.
Inferno 3.81–84.

and when Dante asks whether the agonies of the damned will “be the same, or more, or less, after the final sentence?” Virgil replies:

                        “Look to your science again
where it is written: the more a thing is perfect
the more it feels of pleasure and of pain.
As for these souls, though they can never soar
to true perfection, still in the new time
they will be nearer it than they were before.”
Inferno 6.103–108.

In the context of Inferno we can perhaps doubt some of these claims; after all, the devil is “a liar and the father of lies” (Inf. 23.141) and maybe Virgil’s view of the matter is coloured by the hopelessness of existence in Limbo. But in Paradiso the eagle of justice says:

But see how many now cry out ‘Christ! Christ!’
who shall be farther from him at the Judgment
than many who, on earth, did not know Christ.
Such Christians shall the Ethiopian scorn
when the two bands are formed to right and left,†
one blest to all eternity, one forlorn.
Paradiso 19.106–111.
† Matthew 25:31–46.

In these passages Dante was expressing the orthodox position. Aquinas says:

As reward is to merit, so is punishment to guilt. Now, according to Divine justice, an eternal reward is due to temporal merit: Every one who seeth the Son and believeth in Him hath (Vulg.,—that everyone … may have) life everlasting.† Therefore according to Divine justice an everlasting punishment is due to temporal guilt.
Further, according to the Philosopher‡ (Ethic. v. 5), punishment is meted according to the dignity of the person sinned against, so that a person who strikes one in authority receives a greater punishment than one who strikes anyone else. Now whoever sins mortally sins against God, Whose commandments he breaks, and Whose honor he gives another, by placing his end in some one other than God. But God’s majesty is infinite. Therefore whoever sins mortally deserves infinite punishment; and consequently it seems just that for a mortal sin a man should be punished for ever.
Summa Theologiae 3.99.1.
† John 6:40. The translators’ parenthetical comment points out that the Vulgate text, unlike the Authorized Version, uses the subjunctive mood here (habeat meaning “may have”). ‡ Aristotle.

Moreover, universal salvation is motivated in part by pity for the damned, but the narrative arc of the Divine Comedy moves away from this emotion. In Inferno, Dante expresses “pity for the sorrow of those kinsmen and lost lovers” Francesca and Paolo (Inf. 6.1–2), and tells the glutton Ciacco, “your agony weighs on my heart and calls my soul to tears” (Inf. 6.55–56), but Beatrice tells Virgil “your anguish does not touch me” (Inf. 2.92) and when Dante weeps for the fortune-tellers in the eighth circle, Virgil rebukes him:

“Still like the other fools? There is no place
for pity here. Who is more arrogant
within his soul, who is more impious
than one who dares to sorrow at God’s judgment?”
Inferno 20.27–30.

Again, this was the orthodox position. Aquinas says of the blessed that they will feel pleasure, not pity, when they contemplate the suffering of the damned:

Wherefore in order that the happiness of the saints may be more delightful to them and that they may render more copious thanks to God for it, they are allowed to see perfectly the sufferings of the damned.
Summa Theologiae 3.94.1.


Ripheus or Rhipeus? Just checking, in case it's a typo, but I guess rather it's Virgil's Aeneid (or its translation) rendering the name slightly differently from the other sources.

Virgil writes "Rhipeus", Dante "Rifëo", English translators and commentators on Dante "Ripheus". I have gone with the last for consistency.
